# Create multiple files

Tags: java, file

I have this code:

```
try {

    File file = new File(something+counter+".txt");

    counter++;

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need to make it like this: When they press enter, new file will be created in defined location (I made JTextField for this), but when they press it again, the file OVERWRITES. That's the problem. I need them to press enter - create new file: sample1.txt, press enter again, create new file: sample2.txt

Comment: Can you print file.getAbsoluteFile()? Is it equal to something+counter+".txt" ?

Answer (score 1):

OK by looking at your code now, it looks fine, but you probably declared the counter variable within the method. If so, it will be 'reset' to whatever you set it to every time the method is called.

**EDIT:**

This should work.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Example ex = new Example();
       ex.writeFile();
       ex.writeFile();
    }

    private void writeFile() {
        try {
            File file = new File("file" + counter + ".txt");

            counter++;
            System.out.println("Writing to " + file.toString());

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("content");
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private int counter = 0;
}
```

I get

Writing to file0.txt

Writing to file1.txt

as output and both files have the string 'content' written in them.

**EDIT2:**

Call writefile whenever the user presses enter.

Comment: It overwrites, I don't want it to... That's the problem. How to solve it?